# How to center elements inside a column in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How to center elements inside the first Column which is embedded inside a Row:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Row {
                    Column(modifier = LayoutPadding(top = 16.dp)) {
                        Text(text = "Centered ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
                    }
                    Column {
                        Text(text = "Line One ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
                        Text(text = "Line Two ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

In this example I hardcoded padding, but was not able to figure out how to center the elements out of the box. If there is no such an option, how can I get a height of the whole Row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [**`Modifier.align`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#align) in your `Column`

```
Row (){
    Column( modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)){
        Text(text = "Centered ", style = textStyle)
    }
    Column {
        Text(text = "Line One ", style = textStyle)
        Text(text = "Line Two ", style = textStyle)
    }
}
```

[image]

or you can use the **`verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically`** in the `Row` element:

```
Row (verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){
    Column(){
        Text(text = "Centered ", style = textStyle)
    }
    Column() {
        Text(text = "Line One ", style = textStyle)
        Text(text = "Line Two ", style = textStyle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Container(alignment = Alignment.TopCenter) or Center{} will help you.

Try this,

```
    MaterialTheme {
        Row {
            Container(width = 200.dp) {
                Center {
                    Column() {
                        Text(text = "Centered ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
                    }
                }
            }
            Column {
                Text(text = "Line One ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
                Text(text = "Line Two ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
            }
        }
    }
```

or

```
    MaterialTheme {
        Row {
            Container(width = 200.dp, alignment = Alignment.TopCenter) {
                    Column() {
                        Text(text = "Centered ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
                    }
            }
            Column {
                Text(text = "Line One ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
                Text(text = "Line Two ", style = TextStyle(fontSize = 30.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
            }
        }
    }
```